# why constant char array is modified here when strtok() is used

Tags: c, string, constants, strtok

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    const char a[99]="hello-hi";
    printf("%s\n",a);
    char *p=strtok(a,"-");
    printf("%s",a);
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
hello-hi
hello
```

why a is modified here?? I made it const but still why it is modified??

Comment: Because `strtok` modifies the string.

Comment: This looks like a C question. Is the C++ tag relevant?

Comment: yeah how strtok can modify const string??

Comment: Part of the trouble is that you did not `#include <string.h>` before using `strtok()`.  You also ignored compiler warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `const  char` array does not have to be in read-only memory. Attempt to modify it is an Undefined Behaviour. Anything may happen segfault, modification, virus activation, bank account transfer, disk erase etc etc.

2. Read the **compiler warnings**

```
<source>:9:20: warning: passing 'const char [99]' to parameter of type 'char *' discards qualifiers [-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]
    char *p=strtok(a,"-");
```

3. `int main()` should be `int main(void)`

Answer (score 3):

The definition of `const` is not “the computer will prevent you from modifying the object”. The definition of `const` in C 2018 6.7.3 7 is:

> If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a const-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-const-qualified type, the behavior is undefined…

So defining an object with `const` does not create a promise from the computer to you that the object will not be modified. It is actually a promise in the other direction: It is a promise from you to the computer that you will not attempt to modify the object. This gives the compiler permission to put the object in memory that is marked read-only.

If you violate the promise, the behavior is not defined by the C standard. The object might be in read-only memory, and attempting to modify it will cause a trap and alert you to a bug in your program. Or the object might be in modifiable memory, and attempting to modify it will modify it. Or, with program optimization, other behaviors may occur.

The C standard does give you some help with this. When you pass a `const char *` to `strtok`, which expects a `char *`, the compiler is required to issue a diagnostic message. Pay attention to the warnings and errors the compiler reports and use them to fix your program. Preferable, use a compiler switch to elevate warnings to errors. (`-Werror` with GCC or Clang, `/WX` with Microsoft Visual C++.)

Answer (score 2):

> why a is modified here??

`strtok` modifies the string. Modifying const object results in undefined behaviour. The behaviour of the example program is undefined.

In fact, the const array doesn't convert to pointer to non-const (without cast), so the program is ill-formed.

---

Other problems:

- You don't include the header that declares `strtok`.
- `int main()` is non-standard in C.

Answer (score 1):

From the C Standard (6.7.3 Type qualifiers)

> 6 If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a
> const-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-const-qualified
> type, the behavior is undefined.

The compiler should issue at least a warning that the call of `strtok` discards the qualifier `const` from the passed argument expression.

In this call of `strtok`

```
char *p=strtok(a,"-");
```

the array a is implicitly converted to pointer of the type `const char *` to its first element while the corresponding parameter of the function does not have the qualifier `const`.